# Dealing with ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10: '1 733'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

so I am trying to cut off (convert from object to int dtype) the m^2 from the Erf Size column in the dataset using the following code: train['Erf Size'] = train['Erf Size'].str[:-2].astype(int)

However I am getting this error statement instead ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10: '1 733'

Please kindly help.

[image: dataset]

Comment: `train['Erf Size'].str[:-2].str.replace('\s', '').astype(int)`?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most efficient way to get rid of a string in a df/col but the code below is working.

The method used is [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv('bernard.csv', encoding='ansi')

train[['Size', 'm²']] = train['Erf Size'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
train['Erf Size'] = train['Size']
train.drop(['Size', 'm²'], axis=1,  inplace=True)
```

##### >>> train

[image]